# Android HTTPPost body parsing

Tags: java, android, xml, parsing

I am having a really challenging time parsing some XML data returned to my Android app.
The data is sent as XML but printing it on my mobile screen, it comes out as the following:

```
{"sessid":"5eed0b52c6953b52e262b559b5557be4","session_name":"SESS6cbf091341a26e4687fa7850b465755a,"user":{"uid":"15","name":"guest","pass":"084e0343a0486ff05530df6c705c8bb4","mail":"adeoduye@hotmail.com", "mode":"0","sort":"0","threshold":"0","theme":"","signature":"","signature_format":"0","created":"1306008217","access":"1306094503","login":"1306134979","status":"1","timezone":"3600","language":"","picture":"","init":"adeoduye@hotmail.com","data":a:1:{s:13:\"form_build_id\";s:37:\"form-49ea7a4ef10a8a2b31478696f17e8dee\";","form_build_id":"form-49ea7a4ef10a8a2b31478696f17e8dee","roles":{"2":"authenticated user","3":"guest"}}}
```

Can anyone please help a newbie and give me some ideas on how to parse this type of output and/or plain XML?

Answer (score 2):

This isn't XML but JSON. You have to parse that string using the [JSON API](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/package-summary.html).

Basically you create a `JSONObject` by feeding the string into a [`JSONTokenizer`](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONTokener.html). You can now query the values from the `JSONObject` as described in the API reference example.

Answer (score 1):

The String you're seeing here is in JSON format. You can parse this in Andriod using the following library : http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/

For more info on json, checkout http://json.org.